# Need to grey out a question (having radio button as answer) in HTML/JS application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to grey out the question and there multiple answer using a single click button. I have used below code but it is not working nothing happen after I click `NA`.

HTML:

```js
$("#na").click(function() {
   $(".question1").attr('disabled',true); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-1-questions">
<div style="background-color:greenyellow;"> <b>Question 1:</b> </div><br>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<div class="row1">
   <div class = "question1">
  <legend id="q1" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-0"><b>1) Business leaders demonstrate. effective sponsorship for new ways of working</b></legend>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                            Never
                        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                            Rarely
                        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Occasionally
                          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios4" value="4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                Often
                            </label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios5" value="5">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                            Always
                        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
    <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
    <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">100</span></p>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="disable1" id = "na" value="N/A"  />
</div>
```

Please check the code and help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is it that you want to change the way it look? if yes, then you can add class/style that would change color to appear gray on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently adds the `disabled` attribute to a `div`, which doesn't do anything.

If you want to disable the children inputs, just change your selector to `.question1 input` which selects all inputs that are children of `div`s with the `question1` class:

```js
$("#na").click(function() {
  $(".question1 input").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-1-questions">
  <div style="background-color:greenyellow;"> <b>Question 1:</b> </div><br>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="question1">
        <legend id="q1" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-0"><b>1) Business leaders demonstrate. effective sponsorship for new ways of working</b></legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                                      Never
                                                  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                                      Rarely
                                                  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                      Occasionally
                                                    </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios4" value="4">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                                          Often
                                                      </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios5" value="5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                                      Always
                                                  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
          <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
          <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">100</span></p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" name="disable1" id="na" value="N/A" />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just disable the div! You need to disable all element in the `question1` with below code:

```
$(".question1").find('*').attr('disabled', true);
```

```js
$("#na").click(function () {
            $(".question1").find('*').attr('disabled', true);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 
<div class="section-1-questions">
        <div style="background-color:greenyellow;"> <b>Question 1:</b> </div><br>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="question1">
                    <legend id="q1" class="col-form-label col-sm-8 pt-0"><b>1) Business leaders demonstrate. effective sponsorship for new ways of working</b></legend>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                Never
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                Rarely
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                Occasionally
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios4" value="4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                Often
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline section-1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios5" value="5">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                Always
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
                        <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
                        <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">100</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" name="disable1" id="na" value="N/A" />
    </div>
```